# How to sort a List View in OpenERP based on a integer field in descending order?

Tags: odoo

I am using OpenERP8, I have a functional field 'pending_since' of type integer which calculates no. of days from when the quotation was sent.
I need to display the list view in desc order based on that functional field ('pending_since').

I don't want to use _order='pending_since desc' in .py file, as I have multiple tree views for the same model and for each I want to use different sorting.

I need a XML code which will sort the tree view in desc order, please help

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use this functional field data to sort the records, then you have to use store condition in your functional field

Comment: if i will store it, it wont be reinitialized at runtime and would be of no use.